# how to open Map Expert in Crystal report

Tags: c#, dictionary, crystal-reports

I need to show an world map with area code in report of c# application. Searching through googling i got some idea to add map in crystal report EG:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeryxAC9dFg

[image]

but in my crystal report report i did not get map expert option. how to add a map with area code in report ? 
 please any one know this ???
Thanks in advice

[image]

Comment: What happens to you when you click on map icon?

Comment: Iam not getting Map icon thats my problem.

Comment: Then try to go Insert->Map?

Comment: I need to add world map in my report i'm not getting map expert in my report

Comment: Have you tried "insert->map"?

Comment: please see my question. i'm not having that option

Comment: Which version of CR you use?

Comment: My version is CRforVS_13_0_15 .

Comment: I'v added answer why you don't see map icon and map expert. If it helped you feel free to accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Crystal reports is not supported with Geographic maps (check picture).

[image]

For all things your version miss you can check  [this](https://www.sap.com/bin/sapcom/en_us/downloadasset.2009-01-jan-20-08.comparison-of-features-by-version-for-the-sap-crystal-reports-family-of-offerings-pdf.html) document.